# jqgrid data xml property

Tags: jqgrid

my xml like this: `test.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root> 
    <R c="0" n="a"/>
    <R c="1" n="b"/>
    <R c="2" n="c"/>
</root>
```

how can bind to jqGrid? i tried like this:

```js
jQuery("#ourunittb").jqGrid({
    url: 'test.xml',
    datatype: "xml",
    height: 1000,
    colNames: ['mycode, 'myname'],
    colModel: [
        { width: 60, xmlmap: "root>R>c" },
        { width: 90, xmlmap: "root>R>n" }
    ],
    xmlReader: {
        root: "root",
        row: "R",
        repeatitems: false
    }, 
    rowNum: 1000,
    autowidth: true             
});
```

But I can't get data. Please help me. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of jqGrid supports functions inside of `xmlReader` and `xmlmap` (see my original feature request [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/more-flexibility-in-the-xmlreader/#p25084)). So you can modify your JavaScript code to the following:

```js
$("#ourunittb").jqGrid({
    url: 'test.xml',
    datatype: "xml",
    height: 'auto',
    colModel: [
        { name: 'mycode', width: 80, sorttype: 'int',
            xmlmap: function (obj) {
                return $(obj).attr('c');
            }},
        { name: 'myname', width: 90, xmlmap: function (obj) {
                return $(obj).attr('n');
            }}
    ],
    xmlReader: {
        root: "root",
        row: "R",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    loadonce: true,
    rowNum: 1000
});
```

The results you can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/XmlWithAttributes.htm):

[image]

I added `loadonce: true` option and the `sorttype` property to support local sorting in the loaded grid. In the same way you can use local paging and local filtering of the data (using [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) or [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#calling_conventions))

Comment: Thanks a million. I really appreciate it.I really don’t know what I would have done without your help.