# how to map an attribute of an xml node inside another node to a column in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, xml-parsing

Below is the XML i want to map to columns in jqGrid :

```
<ProtoRequestInfo NPO = "102922">
    <ProtoRequest
        No = "84P6-11-00002"
        Requestor = "Daniel Frank(E677648)"
        CustomerName = "TLV BMW"
        CustomerOrder = ""
        MWO = "4601302"
        PartNumber = "813818-0003"
        ProductType = "CHRA"
        CreationDate = "12-May-2011"
        ABCClasification = "B - Durability testing / Production supplier-soft tooling"
        ProtoStatus = "Closed"
        UsageType = "Assembly Request"
        BOMAvailabilityDate = "13-May-2011"
        BOMCommitedDate = ""
        Technology = "VNT Step3 REA"
        Plant = "84P6-Thaon Les Vosges"
        EstimatedBudget_USD = "0.00">
        <Production
            No = "102219281"
            Status = "Closed"
            SalesOrder = ""
            <RequestedDeliveryDetails Date = "01-Aug-2011" Quantity = "48"/>
            <AgreedDetails Date = "29-Sep-2011" Quantity = "48"/>
            <EstimatedDetails Date = "24-Aug-2011" Quantity = "47.0"/>
            <EstimatedDetails Date = "20-Sep-2011" Quantity = "1.0"/>
            <Info>No Qty Shipped</Info>
        </Production>
    </ProtoRequest>
</ProtoRequestInfo>
```

How the colmodel should be to map the following things into a column ?

1. Sales Order under Production tag
2. Date under Requested Delivery Details tag
3. Quantity under Requested Delivery Details tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `xmlmap` attribute for columns `SalesOrder`, `Date` and `Quantity` and define `xmlmap` as function. The function will get the main element (I am not sure `<ProtoRequestInfo>` or `<ProtoRequest>`) as parameter. You can get the attribute which you need inside of `xmlmap` and return it from the function `xmlmap`.

You can find an example of working with XML attributes in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9292097/315935) (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/XmlWithAttributes.htm)).

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ReadAttrFromXml.htm) shows how to read XML data in the format which you posted. The results are like on the picture below

[image]

I used the following code in the demo:

```js
$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "xml",
    url: "ReadAttrFromXml.xml",
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    height: "auto",
    rowNum: 10000, // no local paging
    colModel: [
        {name: "No", xmlmap: function (obj) {
            return $(obj).attr("No");
        }},
        {name: "Requestor", width: 130, xmlmap: function (obj) {
            return $(obj).attr("Requestor");
        }},
        {name: "CustomerName", width: 120, xmlmap: function (obj) {
            return $(obj).attr("CustomerName");
        }},
        {name: "SalesOrder", xmlmap: function (obj) {
            return $(obj).find(">Production").attr("SalesOrder");
        }},
        {name: "Date", formatter: "date", formatoptions: {srcformat: "d-M-Y"}, align: "center",
            sorttype: "date",
            xmlmap: function (obj) {
                return $(obj).find(">Production>RequestedDeliveryDetails").attr("Date");
            }},
        {name: "Quantity", formatter: "integer", sorttype: "integer", align: "right",
            xmlmap: function (obj) {
                return $(obj).find(">Production>RequestedDeliveryDetails").attr("Quantity");
            }}
    ],
    cmTemplate: {width: 100},
    xmlReader: {
        root: "ProtoRequestInfo",
        row: "ProtoRequest",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "[No]"
    }
});
```

The most important are implementations of `xmlmap` functions and `xmlReader`.

Comment: colModel :[ 
      {name:'No', index:'No', width:80, xmlmap:'[No]'},
      {name:'Requestor', index:'Requestor', width:80, xmlmap:'[Requestor]'},
      {name:'CustomerName', index:'CustomerName', width:80, xmlmap:'[CustomerName]'}]

Comment: xmlReader: { 
      root:"ProtoRequestInfo",
       row:"ProtoRequest",
       repeatitems:false
    }

Comment: i have added colModel and xmlReader as above. Could you please help me to map the sales order which is under a child of Protorequest tag ?

Comment: If i give "ProtoRequest" for "row" attribute in xmlReader i can access the attributes for it. In the similar way how can i access the attributes of "Production" tag which is a child of "ProtoRequest" tag?

Comment: @user2111302: Look at the **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: I got the answer :) sorry for the inconvenience caused.