# How to map xml sub nodes to jqgrid

Tags: xml, jqgrid, xml-parsing

```
<ProtoRequest
        No = "84P6-11-00023"
        Requestor = "Daniel Frank(E677648)"
        CustomerName = "TLV BMW"
        CustomerOrder = ""
        MWO = "4601302"
        PartNumber = ""
        ProductType = ""
        CreationDate = "24-Jun-2011"
        ABCClasification = ""
        ProtoStatus = "Closed"
        UsageType = "Component Request"
        BOMAvailabilityDate = ""
        BOMCommitedDate = ""
        Technology = ""
        Plant = "84P6-Thaon Les Vosges"
        EstimatedBudget_USD = "0.00">
        <LineItem
            PartNumber = "805069-009A"
            Description = "Hsg-Comp retouche"
            RequestQty = "1"
            Supplier = ""
            RequestedDeliveryDate = "29-Jun-2011"
            LineStatus = "Closed"
            SalesOrder = "1654130"
            Item = "10"
            StandardLeadTime = "23"
            ABCClassification = "-1"
            AgreedDate = ""
            EstimatedCost_USD = "0.0"/>
        <LineItem
            PartNumber = "811352-006A"
            Description = "hsg comp retouche"
            RequestQty = "1"
            Supplier = ""
            RequestedDeliveryDate = "28-Jun-2011"
            LineStatus = "Partially Closed"
            SalesOrder = "1654130"
            Item = "20"
            StandardLeadTime = "23"
            ABCClassification = "-1"
            AgreedDate = ""
            EstimatedCost_USD = "0.0"/>
        <LineItem
            PartNumber = "811352-006A"
            Description = "Hsg-Comp retouche"
            RequestQty = "1"
            Supplier = ""
            RequestedDeliveryDate = "28-Jun-2011"
            LineStatus = "Partially Closed"
            SalesOrder = "1654130"
            Item = "20"
            StandardLeadTime = "23"
            ABCClassification = "-1"
            AgreedDate = ""
            EstimatedCost_USD = "0.0"/>
    </ProtoRequest>
```

The above is the xml structure which i want to map to jqGrid.

my xmlReader is:

```
xmlReader: { 
     root:"ProtoRequestInfo",
     row:"ProtoRequest",
     repeatitems:false
      }
```

Now i need 4(No. of "LineItemNo" tag) rows to be created with this info in the main grid itself but not the subgrid.

Expected Output:

```
No              Requestor               PartNumber     Description
____________________________________________________________________________
84P6-11-00023   Daniel Frank(E677648)   805069-009A    Hsg-Comp retouche
84P6-11-00023   Daniel Frank(E677648)   811352-006A    hsg comp retouche
...........
...........
```

how the colmodel should be ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row:"ProtoRequest>LineItem"` inside of `xmlReader` and follow to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090067/315935) on your previous question: to use `xmlmap` defined as function. To read `Requestor` of `ProtoRequest` you can use [jQuery.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method inside of `xmlmap` function.